# compiling legacy Sweave with RStudio 0.99.902

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, sweave

I'm having multiple problems with the “sos” vignette in the “sos” package that has been on CRAN since 2009.  I recently noticed that it fails in multiple ways, and I can't figure out how to fix several of the problems.  "Compile PDF" on “sos.Rnw” in RStudio with R 3.3.0 under Mac OS X 10.11.5 produced an XQuartz pop-up as follows:

```
>Sweave Noweb Syntax?
>>It seems you are using the Sweave-specific syntax in line(s) 
>>9, 15, <snip>;  you may need Sweave2knitr("sos.Rnw") to 
>>convert it to knitr'.
```

I did the following, as it asked:

```
Sweave2knitr('sos.Rnw')
```

This produced a file 'sos-knitr.Rnw'.  I opened this file in RStudio and clicked 'Compile PDF'.  I got one line only:

```
>Loading required package: knitr"
```

If I got anything else, I don't know where it went.

Any suggestion on how I can get past this?
Thanks, Spencer Graves

Answer (score 2):

RStudio is using `knitr` by default instead of `sweave` to generate the code. Revert this decision by doing the following:

RStudio:

Tools -> Global Options -> Sweave -> Weave Rnw files using: `Sweave`

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to switch that in the code?  Most of my vignette work these days uses RMarkdown.  Spencer Graves

Comment: Only project specific environments if you are opting to use the compile button.

Comment: try [`% !Rnw weave = Sweave`](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532247?version=0.99.891&mode=desktop)

Comment: I always use projects, so "Tools -> Project Options ..." seemed to do most of what I wanted.

Comment: After that change, "Compile PDF" identified 3 issues.  I added "% !Rnw weave = Sweave", and "Compile PDF" identified 11 issues, so I reverted "% !Rnw weave = Sweave".  I need to study the remaining 3 issues.  Thanks.  Spencer

Comment: After converting with Sweqave2knitr I found it useful to work on the vignette outside the package structure until it looked right.  It took several passes